# Is a Dolby Vision TV compatible with HDR10 content?

Tags: tv, home-theater, hdr

I apologize if this isn't the correct forum to ask, I couldn't find the right place (please redirect me if necessary).

My father recently bought a Toshiba 43" 4K UHD HDR LED Fire Smart TV model on sale [(43LF711C20)](https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/toshiba-43-4k-uhd-hdr-led-fire-smart-tv-43lf711c20/13325281) after his old TV kicked the bucket.
When he got home I looked over the box and couldn't find any mention of HDR. I then found out that the TV supports Dolby Vision which is a proprietary form of HDR as compared to the open standard HDR10. My question is, will this Dolby Vision TV be capable of playing video files that use both Dolby Vision and HDR10 formatting, or are we better of exchanging the TV for last years model (43LF621C19) that doesn't support Dolby Vision but does support more basic HDR which I can only assume would be HDR10. Seen here: [(43LF621C19)](https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/toshiba-43-4k-uhd-hdr-led-smart-tv-43lf621c19-fire-tv-edition/12598562).

The reason why I'm asking is that most of my 4K HDR movie files are HDR10 compatible, so whether or not Dolby Vision is a superior format doesn't really matter if the TV can't play my files and they all end up looking washed out.

The only relevant info I can find is *"This means that a Dolby Vision-enabled Ultra HD Blu-ray can also play back in HDR10 on TVs that only support that format."* from [Dolby Vision HDR: everything you need to know](https://www.whathifi.com/us/advice/dolby-vision-hdr-everything-you-need-to-know)

Thank's in advance!

Comment: How does your reference link, which seems to be accurate and complete, not answer your question?  *Dolby Vision meets all the requirements to display HDR10 content based on my research*

Comment: The article states that Dolby Vision Blu-Rays (content) can be played on HDR10 devices, but doesn't specifically state the other way around. It then later states "Philips has also decided to offer both HDR10 and Dolby Vision support " which seems redundant if Dolby Vision is already backwards compatible with HDR10. I'm not  knowledgable about AV topics and was looking for a more direct answer. Thanks for you're reply.

Comment: HDR10 and HDR are not identical.  Only you can decide if you want to exchange the product for a different product.  The research I have found on Dolby Vision indicates that while it's based on HDR10+, a television that supports Dolby Vision would only know what to do with 12-bit color.  HDR10+ content only has 10-bits.  While it's possible the extra 2-bits would simply be 0's that isn't guaranteed.  *What would be more likely to happen is whatever device was offering the HDR10 content would not detect a compatible display.*